# strchr implementation in c is it possible to make this work?

Tags: c

please help me out , I'm trying to implement `strchr` and I still get `Null` when I run this code... what is it wrong with it?

```
char *ft_strchr(const char *str, int c)
{
    int i;
    char *temp;

    i = 0;
    while (str[i])
    {
        if (str[i] == c)
        {
            *temp = str[i];
            return (temp);
        }
        else
            return (NULL);
        i++;
    }
    return (str);
}
```

Comment: You're indirecting through `temp`, but you never initialized it. What is `*temp = str[i]` supposed to do?

Comment: At least 4 things wrong. `temp = what?`, `else return (NULL);` - just continue `return (str);` --> `NULL`, type of `i`.  Handling `c==0`

Comment: Please, when asking about a run time problem, post code that cleanly compiles and still shows the problem.

Comment: suggest stepping through the code with a debugger

Comment: on first iteration through the while() loop (suggest using a for() loop instead.  I.E. `for( i=0; str[i]; i++ )`,   the posted code says: `if str[0] != c, then return NULL`.     What about all the other characters in `str`?   I.E. only the first char in `str` is being checked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char* ft_strchr(const char *str, int c){
size_t i;
char *temp;

i = 0;
   while (str[i])
   {
       if (str[i] == c)
       {
           temp = &str[i];
           return temp;
       }
     i++;
   }

   if(str[i]==c)
   {
      return &str[i];
   }

   return NULL;
   // You need to return NULL after scanning whole line..
   // Or it will send NULL checking after 1st character 
}
```

Comment: @chux, now? Is it ok?

Comment: Looks good.  May need `(char*) &str[i]` to quiet warnings.  Candidate simplification:  `do { if (*str == c) return (char *) str } while (*str++);` and drop `size_t i;  if(str[i]==c) { return &str[i]; }`

Answer (score 1):

`strchr` is supposed to return a pointer to the matching character in the string. You're returning a pointer, but it doesn't point into the string. You never initialized it, so it doesn't point anywhere.

Change

```
*temp = str[i];
```

to:

```
temp = &str[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

the following code:

- makes use of the fact the C passes by value rather than by reference
- eliminates the code clutter,
- uses a `for()` statement so the compiler handles all the loop details,
- eliminates all the code clutter

Note: this kind of expression: `*str` evaluates to true, except when the char pointed at is '\0'.

So the below code walks through the passed in char string, terminating on either of two conditions.

```
1) a matching char is found in the string or 
2) end of string is encountered.
```

The return statement returns NULL if end of string is encountered, else returns the address of where the matching char is first found in the string.

```
char    *ft_strchr(const char *str, int c)
{
    for( ; *str && (*str != c); str++ ) ;

    return ( *str? str : NULL);
}
```